# Parse PHP SDK Parse Query with Session Token

Tags: php, sdk, parse-platform

I'm building an app using the new Parse PHP SDK. How can in include the user session token inside a ParseQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the ParseSessionStorage in your code, you can make use of the getCurrentUser() method in the SDK.

```
session_start();

// Init parse: app_id, rest_key, master_key
ParseClient::initialize('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz');

$storage = new ParseSessionStorage();
ParseClient::setStorage( $storage );

$user = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();
```

You can then get the session token as follows:

```
$sessionToken = ParseUser::getCurrentUser()->getSessionToken();
```

You don't need to pass the session into calls. It will automatically use the session if available.

Comment: any simpler way to achieve the same? saw your blogpost for beginners to php+parse as well. Trust me I'm complete beginner

Comment: This is by far the simplest method to achieve this.

Comment: yes, did my own bit of trial and errors, and achieved it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Cristiana214 the library you are using it's the same as the Official Parse PHP SDK. You should update your code to use the Official Parse PHP SDK to make use of the new functions. The library you're using hasn't been updated in over a year.

Comment: @NirajShah how to use the Official Parse PHP SDK with codeigniter framework? that is why i chose the library because it  fits to codeigniter.

Comment: This tutorial covers how to use the SDK: https://www.webniraj.com/2014/08/05/parse-com-using-the-official-parse-php-sdk-v1-0-x/. As for CodeIgniter integration, you'll have to integrate it yourself.

Comment: Official Parse PHP SDK is much more useful than the link.

Comment: I was able to simply call `$sessionToken = ParseUser::getCurrentUser()->getSessionToken()` without the `ParseSessionStorage();` bits